# iPhone Creating a Custom logging Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, logging

I Have developing a iPhone app here i want to using my custom log to store the application events.
is there any link and out there in market to create custom logging class and my requirement is like have to create separate log file for each day.

any idea and suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) + [NSFileHandle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) + [UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification) = Custom Logging with a separate log file for each day.

Comment: thanks for quick response here also have to append my app logs too which i passing to same file during run time... and also is there any detailed description is out there in market ?

Comment: Check out this Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799050/is-there-a-logging-framework-log4j-style-for-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

Review the open source [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) project for a complete and full-featured solution including remote logging, and a viewing application for OS X.